# Apache user can't create files in 777 directory

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, chmod, selinux

I'm not using SELinux, and still I can't get the apache user to create files in my cache storage directory. Can this work without using `chown` to change the user to the actual apache user?

```
[root@server live_storage]# getenforce
Disabled
[root@server live_storage]# su -s /bin/bash -c 'touch /home/admin/live_storage/c50d02d942c0a3d.cache' apache
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/admin/live_storage/c50d02d942c0a3d.cache’: 
Permission denied
[root@server admin]# ls -lsa 
total 84 
  4 drwx------. 10 admin admin  4096 24 mei 10:32 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x.  3 root  root   4096  9 mei 11:12 ..
  4 drwxrwxrwx   3 admin admin  4096 24 mei 10:33 live_storage

[admin@server live_storage]$ touch '/home/admin/live_storage/c50d02d942c0a3d.cache'
[admin@server live_storage]$ ls '/home/admin/live_storage/c50d02d942c0a3d.cache'
/home/admin/live_storage/c50d02d942c0a3d.cache
```

Comment: Did `/home/admin/live_storage/c50d02d942c0a3d.cache` file exist before you tried touch as apache?

Comment: @DusanBajic Hi, no it did not. The whole directory is empty

Comment: `[root@server live_storage]# su -s /bin/bash -c 'touch /home/admin/live_storage//c50d02d942c0a3d.cache' `
`touch: cannot touch ‘/home/admin/live_storage//c50d02d942c0a3d.cache’: Permission denied`
`[root@server live_storage]# su -s /bin/bash -c 'touch /home/admin/live_storage//c50d02d942c0a3d.cache' admin`
`[root@server live_storage]# `

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Apache didn't have execute rights on the `/home/admin` directory. `chmod +x /home/admin` fixed the problem